# What research has been done in the domain of "identifying sarcasm in text"?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, natural-language-understanding, semantics

Identifying sarcasm is considered one of the most difficult open-ended problems in the domain of ML and NLP/NLU.

So, was there any considerable research done on that front? If yes, then what is the accuracy like? Please, also, explain the NLP model briefly.

Comment: http://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2010-05/computer-algorithm-can-recognize-sarcasm-which-soooo-cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following survey article by researchers from IIT Bombay summarizes recent advances in sarcasm detection: [Arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03426).

In reference to your question, I do not think it is considered either extraordinarily difficult or open-ended. While it does introduce ambiguity that computers cannot yet handle, Humans are easily able to understand sarcasm, and are thus able to label datasets for sarcasm detection.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a recent work in the same domain where neural networks(CNNs to be accurate) are used for the same purpose. Some info. about the research is:

> To learn that context, the paper describes a method by which the
>   neural network finds the user’s “embeddings” — i.e. contextual cues
>   like the content of previous tweets, related interests and accounts,
>   and so on. It uses these various factors to plot the user with others,
>   and (ideally) finds that they form relatively well-defined groups.

So, the paper uses CNNs, word and user embeddings for detecting sarcasm in text. There is also a [Techcrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2016/08/04/this-neural-network-tries-to-tell-if-youre-being-sarcastic-online/) on that.

The paper uses sentiment of the tweet and compares with that of the other similar tweets:

> If the sentiment of the tweet seems to disagree with the bulk of what
>   is expressed by similar users, there’s a good chance sarcasm is being
>   employed.

[Link to the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00976v2.pdf)